# Обновление изображения на сайте с определенной периодичностью

Tags: javascript, python, html

Есть страничка, в локальной сети, с которой производится управление роботом, также есть jpg изображение карты, построенной этим роботом, файл с изображением обновляется раз в 4 секунды. Как реализовать  обновление карты в панели управления, синхронно с изменением содержимого файла